# remove items from navigator's context menu

Tags: eclipse-plugin, contextmenu

In my eclipse plugin I have specified my custom navigator using the CNF (Common Navigator Framework). I got everything working except the context menu.

I have created a new viewer-extension for it in which I define a popup-Menu with the respective groups (I overtook all of the groups from the project explorer) and it does get displayed and everything I want to appear in it, does appear.

However there are a bunch of things that appear in it that I don't want to appear.

As an example there is the `Run As...` option in the context menu which I don't want as I have nothing to run anyway. I tried using the Plugin-Menu-Spy in order to find where this menuItem is being contributed but it won't give me any information about it.
I found out that when setting `allowsPlatformContributions = false` in my popUp-Extension the unwanted menuItems disappear but so do the Import and Export menus which I do want to have.

So how can I remove the `Run As...` menuItem from my navigator's context menu? Is there some kind of filter I can apply to it?